# python : reform multiple columns into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, reform

I would like to reform the following dataframe

[image: main data]

into :

[image: reformed data]

Could somebody help me with that, please?

Comment: read ----> [ask]

Comment: @Amir would you be so kind to edit your question with a minimal example of input/output as text? This will be better for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screenshot is not a good format for community to reproduce your code, and data.

That is a shape(m, n) to shape(u, v) problem, probably you don't know the term in **Pandas**, **Numpy**, but still can trynna google "reform", or "reshape".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.shape
###
(9, 12)
```

[image]

We can use `np.hsplit()` and `np.vstack()` to deal with,

shape calculation: (9 × 12) = c×(9 × n), with n = 2

```
# expected output columns  
n = 2

output = np.vstack(np.hsplit(df.values, df.shape[1]/n))
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['node1','node2'])
print(output_df.head(10))
###
   node1  node2
0  38.47  37.86
1  37.63  37.02
2  38.27  37.66
3  38.64  38.03
4  38.12  37.51
5  37.57  36.96
6  37.83  37.22
7  37.62  37.01
8  37.04  36.43
9  40.17  39.52
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me, I realized it's a `hsplit()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the underlying numpy array:

```
n = 2

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,df.shape[1]//n, n)
                    .reshape(-1, n, order='F'),
                  columns=[f'node{i+1}' for i in range(n)])
```

Example:

```
   node1  node2
0      0      1
1      6      7
2      2      3
3      8      9
4      4      5
5     10     11
```

Used input:

```
   0  1  2  3   4   5
0  0  1  2  3   4   5
1  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

*NB. The input must have an even number of columns (or multiple of `n` for the generic case).*